# I want to pivot a table and aggregate a column into strings

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have a select statement producing the following:

```
+---------+---------+------+
| Patient | Pattern | Rank |
+---------+---------+------+
| a       |      0  |    1 |
| a       |      1  |    2 |
| a       |      0  |    3 |
| a       |      0  |    4 |
| b       |       1 |    1 |
| b       |       1 |    2 |
| c       |       0 |    1 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

Desired output:

```
+---------+-----+---+---+---+
| Patient |  1  | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---------+-----+---+---+---+
| a       |   0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| b       |   1 | 1 |   |   |
| c       |   0 |   |   |   |
+---------+-----+---+---+---+
```

Alternate desired output:

```
+---------+----------+
| Patient |  Pattern |
+---------+----------+
| a       |     0100 |
| b       |       11 |
| c       |        0 |
+---------+----------+
```

I know I need to do a pivot, but not much else. I'm using Oracle.

Here's my progress so far:

```
SELECT PATIENT_ID, LISTAGG(PATTERN, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RANK ASC)

FROM

( the query above )

GROUP BY PATIENT_ID;
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?  The `pivot` operator is relatively new.  If you need to support older versions of Oracle, you'll need to use the old `max(case` trick.

Comment: I'm not sure which version it is, but it's definitely a version where pivot is a thing.

Comment: `select * from v$version` will tell you the version.  Are you guaranteed that the `rank` will never exceed 4?

Comment: No. The maximum rank is probably quite a bit higher than 4 and the script should be able to deal with a new dataset where it's higher or lower.

I'll post an alternate desired output that might be simpler to implement. I've never used pivot before so I dunno, though.

I'm using 11.1

Comment: I posted the alt output.

Comment: If the number of columns that you wanted isn't known at compile time, you can't use a `pivot` at least not in a static SQL statement.  You could use dynamic SQL to construct the SQL statement at runtime but that would require running a query first to get the `max(rank)` and then constructing a SQL statement with that number of output columns.  Returning a single string would be easier.

Comment: My boss said that returning a single string is actually preferable. How would I do that, though? I know that the pivot syntax requires an aggregation function, is there a way to use concatenation as an aggregation?

Comment: This is a little different - he's ordering them by the thing he's concatenating and I'm ordering them by a separate column. Also, he's doing it on a table and I'm doing it on a select. Regardless, the solution posted there isn't solving the problem for me.

Comment: Added my attempt at using the solution you posted.

Comment: Can you define "not working"?  What output are you getting for the sample data you provided (I assume in your sample data, patient b's rank 2 row should be a 0 not a 1-- otherwise I'm not sure why the desired string would be 10 rather than 11).

Comment: You were right, I fixed the sample data.

I did some research on the error I got and it turns out that LISTAGG isn't available in 11.1. Any idea what I can do instead?

Comment: In the question I linked to, there is a link to a number of different string aggregation techniques.  Pick one.

Comment: You could also upgrade to 11.2, that has `LISTAGG()`.

Comment: I don't want to delete it because I think it has some information that people could use.